# What elements are in this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Given the set $M = \{n\in\mathbb{N}\ |\ \forall z(z\in\mathbb{N}\rightarrow z\leq n\}$

I think this set is empty. Here's why:

Let $k$ be in the set. Hence, $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $z=k+1$.

So $k+1\leq k$ must hold. But $1\leq 0$ is always false. So there are no elements in $M$.

---

But I'm not really sure because a logical implication is also true if the assumption ($z\in\mathbb{N}$) is false.

So what if $z$ is not in $\mathbb{N}$? Would that make $M$ an infinitely large set? And if so, what elements would be in $M$?

Comment: I'm not a set theorist, but I think "the biggest number" fits the description. Maybe all alephs work here.

Comment: You have a $\forall z$. Thus it suffices to find one $x$ such that $(x\in \mathbb{N}\to x \leq n)$ is false, and the $\forall z(z\in \mathbb{N}\to z \leq n)$ is false.

Comment: @DanielFischer so my proof would be correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but the $1\leq 0$ only says that $0$ isn't in this set, this isn't what you wanted to prove. Suppress the  "But $1\leq 0$ is always false" part and it's fine.

Comment: Yes. But you forgot a closing parenthesis in the definition of $M$.

Comment: (1) If $z\notinBbb N$, then the implication is vacuously true; so you never have to consider those $z$. (2) I take "But $1\le0$ is always false" as an argument showing that $k+1\le k$ is false. Perhaps it would be clearer to write "But subtracting $k$ from both sides yields $1\le 0$ which is false."